# Get world position of touch on objects

Tags: unity, c#, touch

In my Unity3d game, I want to get the world position that was touched, when I touch a specific object, regardless of all objects that are in front of it.

How would I do that, I only know Camera.ScreenPointToRay(...), but for some reason that does not work properly?

---

OK - one cannot answer the question with the information I provided.

In order to determin the point, where the Ray hit the object, I used `RaycastHit.transform.position` (which refers to the Transform object that was hit) as opposed to `RaycastHit.point` (which refers to the `Vector3` in world space, where the `RaycastHit` happened).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a system that prints the position the mouse is hovering over. You will probably want to write a function that doesn't update every frame. When you click it spits out an `Vector3` of the position in worldspace you are hovering over with your mouse in Screen space.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class check : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        // Cast a ray from the mouse position to the world
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        //When the ray hits anything, print the world position of what the ray hits using hit.point
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)  && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
            print(hit.point);
    }
}
```

You can now Instantiate GameObjects with `Instantiate(yourGO,hit.point,Quaternion.identity);`

Answer (score 1):

[Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html) allows you to get the place you clicked on the screen as a point in world space.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a different problem. I tried to spawn objects where I click, but they only get spawned at one position (where the camera was at the start of the scene)
Might this be a problem with UI?